# Paginated list refresh with maintaining scroll position

Tags: android, ios, list, scroll, pagination

I'm wondering how it can be handled.

I have a paginated list that needs to be refreshed pretty frequently. If I go to details of an item, and then back, I'd like to have current data but not lose everything I fetched previously (for example, if I fetched 3 pages I don't want to refresh only the first one). I think that is a common case, but I'm not sure how other people solve it.

My propositions:

1. Always refresh no matter what and ignore scroll position.
2. Request changes that happened between the last update and the current time from the backend.
3. Don't refresh anything, just inform the user that the list may not be up to date, and give the user button for refreshing if they want.
4. Send push from the backend every time something changes and handle it in the app.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest for your problem is either of the 2 solutions -

1. Refresh the screen but before refreshing take a note of the scroll item user was viewing previously, and then refresh the list and scroll to the item if found in the list else just scroll to the top and show a message "List has been refreshed".
2. Request changes that happened between the last update and the current time from the backend and then update the list accordingly same as the first solution.

The second approach is much improved and optimised if your backend permits that.

Happy to help,

Thanks & Happy Coding

Comment: The first option is not possible. I may have fetched 10 pages, it isn't optimal to refresh them all at once.

Comment: Thats what I mentioned in my answer that first is not a good option and should not be followed if your backend can support the second approach.